# Why php needs <?php tag? Simple <? does not work

Tags: php, tags

I've just installed apache 2.2.22, php 5.3.15 and some other stuff on my Windows 7. At some point, the tag `<?` stopped working (apache now returns `<? ..... ?>` as plain HTML). After wasting a lot of time, I noticed that the full version of this tag `<?php` does work! How can I fix it without editing the code?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: This is why it's been a wide spread suggestions since the mid 2000s to always use `<?php` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enable php short tags for `<?` and `<?=` to work in PHP < 5.4. Call `ini_set('short_open_tag', true)` or modify your php.ini if you can to specify it. Some hosts even allow a php.ini within the directory of the php script itself or you can customize your php.ini through your hosting panel.

Comment: As of PHP 5.4, `<?=` is always available regardless of what `short_open_tag` is set to.

Comment: Yes, I know that but in his question he said "I've just installed apache 2.2.22, php 5.3.15 and some other stuff on my Windows 7."

Comment: I understand, I just left the comment because in a vacuum your opening sentence is not true anymore and I don't want anyone stumbling across your answer in the future to get the wrong idea.

Answer (score 7):

Check your [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting in php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

Modify `short_open_tag` in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Using just `<? ?>` is bad practice so use `<?php ?>` or edit `short_open_tag` in your php.ini file.

Comment: Not necessarily. Most hosts now allow some form of overriding so server compatibility does not remain an issue. There are also one-off cases where it creates an error, i.e. when outputting xml inside of a php template.

Comment: Yes it depends on the person's views but there is nothing wrong with short tags. In fact it reduces the amount of typing you have to do. The side effects are very mimimal and if you use SCM you can include the php.ini file or even use php_value inside of htaccess

Comment: True except it's a feature of PHP so it's still technically correct hehe

Feature or bug?